# how to dynamically fill the color of a flutter image

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter.

I want to fluidly fill an empty image with color as shown in the photo below, but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

I haven't tried it because I couldn't find a way.

Please help me as a beginner. thank you

₩₩₩₩₩₩₩₩

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an `svg` image and use *[`flutter-svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)* package to achieve your required design.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fill Image with Color'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FillImageWithColor(
            imageUrl: 'assets/your_icon.svg',
            fillColor: Colors.red,
            baseColor: Colors.grey,
            percentage: 45, // Change this value to control the fill percentage
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FillImageWithColor extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final Color fillColor;
  final Color baseColor;
  final int percentage;

  FillImageWithColor({
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.fillColor,
    required this.baseColor,
    required this.percentage,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fillGradient = LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      end: Alignment.topCenter,
      colors: [
        fillColor,
        fillColor.withOpacity(0),
      ],
      stops: [
        percentage / 100,
        percentage / 100,
      ],
    );

    return Stack(
      children: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
          imageUrl,
          color: baseColor,
        ),
        ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: (bounds) => fillGradient.createShader(bounds),
          blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            imageUrl,
            color: fillColor,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

#### Code Explanation:

Let's talk step by step considering you as a beginner:

1. Install the `flutter_svg` package using `flutter pub add flutter_svg`.
2. Add your image(mandatorily an `svg`) in `assets` folder.
3. Provide the same detail in `pubspec.yaml`

   ```yaml
   assets:
    - assets/your_icon.svg
   ```
4. Now, let's breakdown the code that I attached above in below steps.
5. The `MyApp` class is the root widget of the app. It contains a `MaterialApp` widget that sets up the structure of the app with a simple `Scaffold`, `AppBar`, and a Center widget that contains an instance of the `FillImageWithColor` widget(which is our custom widget).
6. This `FillImageWithColor` widget accepts four parameters:

   - `imageUrl`: The path to the SVG image in the assets folder.
   - `fillColor`: The color to fill the image with up to the specified percentage.
   - `baseColor`: The color of the rest of the image that is not filled with the fillColor.
   - `percentage`: The percentage of the image height that should be filled with the fillColor.
7. **[IMPORTANT]** Inside the `FillImageWithColor` widget, I created a `Stack` widget that will contain two `SvgPicture` widgets stacked on top of each other. The bottom `SvgPicture` widget will display the original image with the `baseColor`, and the top `SvgPicture` widget will display the image filled with the `fillColor` up to the specified percentage.
8. To create the fill effect, I defined a `LinearGradient` called `fillGradient` which has two colors for creating a sharp transition between the filled and non-filled parts of the image.
9. Finally, I applied the `fillGradient` to the top `SvgPicture` widget using a `ShaderMask`. Of course the styles and adding extra icons etc. follows this very same approach and you can edit it as per your requirement.

##### Result:

[image]